# Open ipa within an ipa in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

As stated in my question above, is it possible to have an ipa file within another ipa? To further explain, here is my situation:

I have two apps and the first one calls the other through URL Scheme. I don't have problem with this. But what I need is to install only one ipa file instead of two. And the first thing that came into my mind is to put a .ipa file inside the other .ipa file. I really don't know if this is possible that's why I need your take on this. But if this is not possible, I hope someone can tell me what would be the best practice to doing this kind of thing.

I can make it as one application, but that would be my last solution.

Comment: *"I have two apps and the first one calls the other through URL Scheme."* *"I hope someone can tell me what would be the best practice to doing this kind of thing."* Actually, you answered yourself. This isn't Android - each app (or "ipa") is sandboxed.

Comment: Install both apps

Answer (score 0):

There are no way to use another app in side app. but you can set a screen like.

You need to check with schema that application install in device or not. If not then user need to redirect to app store. User need to install and then while you go with same flow in app that open second app.

referance answer for check app install or not is following: [Detecting programmatically whether an app is installed on iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3808691/detecting-programmatically-whether-an-app-is-installed-on-iphone)

Comment: Thanks for the response,
but I want something like that,
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4800672/android-apk-within-an-apk

Comment: sorry to say but that wont possible with iOS